# Changing the color of a pixel 

Tags: iphone

i am able to read a particular pixel at given CGPoint but i have been looking to change the color of a pixel and it would be highly appreciated if anyone can help me out with a code snippet.

My Code is:

```
unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);       

if (data != NULL) {    
  offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));    
  alpha =  data[offset];     
  red = data[offset+1];             
  green = data[offset+2];           
  blue = data[offset+3];     
  color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0f) 
                   green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f) 
                   alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to do.  If you want to change the pixel's color in the original CGImageRef then you would use something like:

```
// Set the color of the pixel to 50% grey + 50% alpha
data[offset+0] = 128;
data[offset+1] = 128;
data[offset+2] = 128;
data[offset+3] = 128;

// Create a CGBitmapImageContext 
CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(), width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(), kCGImageAlphPremultipliedFirst);

// Draw the bitmap context back to your original context
CGContextDrawImage(bitmapContext, CGMakeRect(...), cgctx);
```

You should make all of your changes to the data* at once and then write the modified bitmap buffer back to the original context.

Comment: thanx mark,
Actually i am trying to implement Flood Fill but i am not able to do that, when i try to match the pixel with its near by pixel value it gives me false.

the scenario is i have a Background image and there are some shapes on it user can select the color from the palette and the with single click i am trying to flood fill the object.

I desperately need help because i am not able to fill the color.

Comment: This goes beyond the scope of a SO question.  You probably need to pick up a book on image processing.  If you should look at CoreImage to see if you can use that.  There is probably an easier way of doing this in CoreImage.

Comment: But Mark CoreImage is not for iPhone.....check this thread.
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1552538

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking MacOS, not iPhone.  On the iPhone I tend to use OpenGL.

Comment: Mark can you give me an example of OpenGL flood fill in a jpg Image?? please help me i am really in a trouble.