# Accessing directly the Iphone 3gs camera

Tags: iphone, camera, real-time, iphone-privateapi

I am attempting to write an real-time image processing application on the iphone.

Currently, I am taking pictures with takepicture method (the uiGetScreeImage output has a too low resolution) but since I receive a UImage from the ImagePickerController, which is 3Mpixels, I have to draw it onto a context and that takes a lot of time. Since I only need a small section of the image I tried cropping it first and then drawing it but it did not really help. Morevoer, the time it takes to draw the cropped image seems to depend on the position of the crop rather than its size (which I find rather strange, but it might have smth to do with the way a UIImage is physicallz stored i guess).

I was wondering if there was a way to access directly the pixels of the image. I am open to any solution. Also if you could point me to some private api page or solution that would work with the iphone 3gs, that would be great (i don't intend to publish the application).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1702.html) can be helpful. Plus you could use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118872/changing-the-color-of-a-pixel)